# Unable to properly register service in Eureka on AWS ECS with dynamic ports on

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I've recently inherited a micro-service system that runs on the spring-boot and netflix stack on AWS ECS, I'm quite new to spring-boot and the netflix side of things.  I'm trying to move this over from using statically defined ports to using dynamic ports so that we can better use existing machines, but I'm having trouble getting the microservices to register themselves in Eureka.

The services are still starting up fine, when they are getting marked as offline in Spring Boot Admin.  When I click on the service name in Spring Boot Admin I see the following links on the top right

```
http://10.128.83.113:32915/
http://10.128.83.113:18080/actuator
http://10.128.83.113:18080/actuator/health
```

`10.128.83.113` is the IP address of this EC2 instance that is part of my ECS cluster, `32915` is the hostPort number that is being used inside the same machine and `18080` is the container port number that the service is binding to inside the docker container.

From reading the conversation at [github.com](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/151) I am setting the parameter `eureka.instance.non-secure-port` to the HostPort and that seems to be setting the port on the topmost of the three links, and from reading [medium.com](https://medium.com/@bhanu.pratap/service-discovery-in-spring-cloud-using-netflix-eureka-in-aws-fargate-2c5c294fee5c) linked to from [github.com](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/937) I am also setting

```
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true 
eureka.instance.ip-address=\${HOST_IP}
```

This is all working fine without the three eureka config items above when I'm using a host network mode in ECS/docker and statically defined ports, but that requires more EC2 instances in a cluster than is necessary.  When I change to using dynamic ports and a bridge network mode (due to the dynamic ports), I just can't get the service to register itself properly in Eureka, I think I'm getting close, but I can't workout what config I'm missing.  Can someone advise on how to go about solving this?  I suspect something is registering the IP address of the docker container or the docker container port number (or both) with Eureka, but I can't see where in Eureka to find logs to confirm/deny that and I don't know what other config I should be setting.

The microsevices are using spring boot v2.0.3.release.  ECS is 1.20.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have managed to get this working, in the end I needed to set 6 parameters they are:

```
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=${EXPOSED_PORT}
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.ip-address=${HOST_IP}
eureka.instance.hostname=${HOST_NAME}
eureka.instance.metadataMap.management.port=${EXPOSED_PORT}
eureka.instance.health-check-url=${HOST_IP}:${EXPOSED_PORT}/actuator/health
```

All of these together have the service registered successfully in Eureka.

Comment: Sir, can you please elaborate a bit, I'm facing the same issue while deploying microsesrvices to the ECS Fargate, where Eureka clients (services) are not sending valid private/public ip address to the eureka server. Also, it would be great if you could share your configuration parameters.

Comment: @SridharC we don't have that many items set in our application.yml file, it's really just `eureka.client.enabled=true

server.port=8080

spring.application.name=applicationName`

Then when docker runs, it executes an entrypoint script, the main line in it is `java -D<option_1_in_answer> -D<option_2_in_answer> ... -D<option_n_in_answer> -jar app.jar`